# how to modify the elements in a Scala List?

Tags: scala

```
var increase  = (x:Int) => x+1
var someNumbers = List(-11, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10)


someNumbers.foreach((x) => increase(x))
```

I want all the elements in the list to be increased by 1. Am I doing something wrong here? the foreach function doesn't do anything

Comment: Substitute `map` for `foreach`, and save the result to a different list.

Comment: `foreach` returns type is `unit` hence you don't find any result. Use some other function like `map`, `collect` etc...

Comment: Hi @Jubobs . You are a genius. Never wondered it had a such simple solution. May I ask why foreach won't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` return unit. That's why it does not do anything.
If you want to modify the list like increasing its value by 1. You need to use `map` which will manipulate and return the modified list.

```
scala> var increase  = (x:Int) => x+1
increase: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1195/148679921@50f13494

scala> var someNumbers = List(-11, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10)
someNumbers: List[Int] = List(-11, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10)

scala> val modifiedList = someNumbers.map((x) => increase(x))
modifiedList: List[Int] = List(-10, -9, -4, 1, 6, 11)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var increase  = (x:Int) => x+1
var someNumbers = List(-11, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10)


someNumbers.map((x) => increase(x))
```

The above worked

Comment: don't use vars. bad solution.